# How to add spaces between the function name and the parenthesis in php-cs-fixer

Tags: php, phpcs, php-cs-fixer

php cs fixer is formatting the code  as follows, by removing space between the function call and the parenthesis

```
-    public function __invoke (array $addedValues, array $args, Context $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
+    public function __invoke(array $addedValues, array $args, Context $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
         return self::determineAddedValues($addedValues);
     }
```

I have to keep the space between the function name and the opening parenthesis. I have the following rules in the config

```
    'single_space_after_construct' => true,
    'no_spaces_after_function_name' => false,
```

[complete rules](https://gist.github.com/ppshobi/136350cc8cab46a2b9627765dadf9a0f)

but the cs fixer removes the space between. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

I am using version `friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer: 3.4.0`, with php 7.4

Comment: Why do you want the space? It is against PSR. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#44-methods-and-functions

Comment: yes, its an old project and I want to keep the styles as is and slowly migrate them.